# Why doesn't refrigerator start immediately after putting the switch on?

Tags: appliances

I've gotten something common. Please don't assume there is a malfunction or default with my refrigerator.

The experiment asks what would happen if I turned off the refrigerator's power source and then turned it back on right away, say after 30 seconds. The refrigerator's primary component, which may be the compressor, takes some time to start. I was curious as to why.

However, if I turn it back on an hour later, the refrigerator's main part turns on right away. How come?

Comment: It takes time for the temperature to rise enough that the compressor is needed? Even plugged in a refrigerator is off a large fraction of the time.

Comment: It sounds like it is working as it should. It may be due to the controls or maybe the clickson. When it is running it compresses the gas condense to a liquid then passes  liquide through a capillary tube (tube with very small hole) to control refrigerant flow. The pressure between the input and the output of the compressor is over 100 PSIG. When the compressor stops the liquid has to go to the gaseous state where it passes through the cap tube into the evaporator. As this happens the high pressure side (liquid) pressure drops and will eventually equal the input (low side) to the compressor.

Answer (score 3):

The compressor's job is to compress the refrigerant and pump it into the "high side" of the system.  This high pressure naturally tries to push back on the compressor, so the compressor has to do real work in order to continue compressing the refrigerant.  The compressor has enough power to do this as long as it keeps running.  If it stopped, it does not have enough power to start moving against the back pressure. If you apply power, it will sit there, stalled, making a humming noise and drawing a lot of current.  And you usually would see the lights dim as well.  This also applies to air conditioners; probably more so.

In older systems, this is exactly what would happen, and after a few seconds a thermal protection switch would open, cutting off power to the compressor.  After some number of seconds, it would cool down enough to close the switch and try again.  The compressor would "cycle" like this several times.  Meanwhile, the pressure is equalizing--there is a restriction between the high and low side and the refrigerant slowly makes its way through over time.  The low side comes back to the other side of the compressor.  When the pressure drops low enough, the compressor starts again and everyone is happy.

In a modern system, the designers often put an electronic timer in that will simply refuse to apply power for a minute or two.  I have even seen this feature in "smart thermostats". So you get the same behavior, with none of the drama.

Comment: This is really about refrigeration and not electronics...some of the answers reflect this :)

Comment: So can you please refer me a relevant site for my query possibly in stack exchange or any other platform ?

Comment: Generally they would suggest "home improvement" (actually, diy), ...where the same people would answer the question anyway :)   Though I like it here because engineering is about "how does it work" and DIY is mostly "I just need this fixed".  Still, I hope I answered your question.

Comment: But I again switch it on the power supply ; say after 1 hour the compressor starts instantly with no drama . Why is it so ?

Comment: The pressure that kept it from starting has dissipated after an hour.  So there's nothing holding the compressor back.

Answer (score 1):

You don't make it clear if the compressor was running when you switched off the power. If the thermostat was open then the power would have been off and will remain off until the temperature rises enough to close the thermostat contacts. Then the compressor will start.

Other factors may include defrost timers, etc., and if a programmable chip has been added then it is little trouble to add time delays to limit the number of compressor starts per hour, door open warnings, over-temperature alarms, etc.

Comment: I am talking about Main AC  power supply  to the refrigerator . If switch off the main power supply ...and again switch on the power supply ; why does compressor takes time to start ?

Comment: "*I am talking about Main AC power supply to the refrigerator.*" So am I. You still haven't clarified whether or not the compressor was running when you switched off the power. Please read my answer again.

Comment: Oh ! So compressor was running at the time while I disconnected the power supply by switching off.

Answer (score 0):

It's designed that way for a number of reasons. A big reason is you don't want it to turn on and off in rapid succession (sometimes even a couple of minutes apart) or else you burn out your compressor motor. Motor starts are hard on the motor.

That also means if the temperature is just above what it should be, you don't want the motor rapidly switching on and off as it straddles the threshold. One solution is to wait to make sure the temperature is past that threshold for a sufficiently long time before reacting. If you unplug the power, you reset whatever was keeping track of that.